# how to keep storing users inputs in a while loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

The user will enter a list of numbers. The user should enter as many numbers as the user wishes. All the numbers should be stored in a variable, I am not trying to add them all up.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   // declare variables
   double number,listOfNumbers; 
   bool condition;

   cout << "Enter a starting number: ";
   cin >> number;

   condition = true;

   while (condition)
   {
      if(number > 0)
      {
         cout << "Enter another number (type 0 to quit): ";
         listOfNumbers = number;
         cin>>listOfNumbers;
      }
      else
      {
         condition=false; 
      }
   }
   cout << listOfNumbers;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your listOfNumbers is a variable of type double. It is not a list of numbers, it is one value at a time only. If you want to build and maintain a list of numbers, then you will have to use a data structure that supports that. A common choice in C++ is std::vector

Comment: The value of number is never changed in your while loop, so if the first number entered is > 0 it is an infinite loop.

Comment: "All the numbers should be stored in a variable" - the plurality of "All the" directly conflicts with the singularity of "a variable", *unless*... unless you're being asked to store the values in a *container* of some sort, and echo them all back after input is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`std:vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to hold the numbers, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // declare variables
   double number;
   vector<double> listOfNumbers; 

   cout << "Enter numbers (type 0 to quit): ";
   while ((cin >> number) && (number != 0))
   {
      listOfNumbers.push_back(number);
   }

   for(number : listOfNumbers)
      cout << number << ' ';

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small modifications and the use of a `std::list`or `std::vector` to store the values, the vector will grow dynamicly as you run the program and relocate if it runs out of space, the list will allocate space for every new item both works here.

I also never use `using namespace std` although  it is very common in tutorials to do.

The syntax `auto const &i` in last for loops requires some of the later C++ standards it will give you a unmutable reference to the item.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
  // declare variables
  double number;
  std::list<double> listOfNumbers;
  bool condition;

  std::cout << "Enter a starting number: ";
  std::cin >> number;

  condition = true;

  while (condition) {
    if (number > 0) {
      listOfNumbers.push_back(number);
      std::cout << "Enter another number (type 0 to quit): ";
      std::cin >> number;
    } else {
      condition = false;
    }
  }

  for (auto const &i : listOfNumbers) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```